# Install and Run PHP in Ubuntu 9.04 Desktop edition in Live mode

Tags: php, 9.04

my system runs on Windows XP, i need to run a PHP project in Ubuntu, but dont want to install Ubuntu on the HDD.
So need to run it in Live mode, now please guide me to install PHP on Ubuntu so i can test my PHP project.

I have `Ubuntu 9.04 Desktop edition`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

typing

```
sudo apt-get install php5 php5-cli
```

should do it.

Have you considered virtualizing your ubuntu installation, so you dont have to install it again in case of testing it again ?

Comment: virtualize UBUNTU on XP ?

Comment: yes, for example with virtualbox or other virtualization software. but it depends on hardware, needs a little bit more ram when compared to running from livecd

Comment: I got 512mb RAM,80gb HDD, 1.8ghz AMD, is it possible to run UBUNTU on XP ?

Comment: hmm, with 512mb ram i would try lubuntu ( same php, just different GUI which needs less memory ). And yes, it should be possible. 

you can look at some tutorials, for example http://www.psychocats.net/ubuntu/virtualbox ( first google result). Just when selecting amount of memory, select less, i guess 256MB should be enough for lubuntu